Error: Cannot find module '/usr/local/lsws/fcgi-bin/lsnode.js'
Recently I deployed my API on shared hosting with nodejs 18.16.0 and everything was working fine. but after 1/2 days it is started to giving this response
503
Service Unavailable
The server is temporarily busy, try again later!

I did not change anything after deploying it, it was working as expected before.
I tried checking logs then I got this one
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1078
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/usr/local/lsws/fcgi-bin/lsnode.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1075:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v18.16.0

I searched on google but did not find anything related to this error,
I restarted my server but still same thing.
here is my package.json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.6.8",
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.12",
    "express": "^4.19.2",
    "qs": "^6.12.0"
  }
}



I'm facing same issue. This way fix my issue:

Create loader.cjs file in your node.js root directiory (same level as package.json)
Copying this code below. (Note: if your main file is not name index.js, rename it)



async function loadApp() {
     await import('./index.js');
}
loadApp();




Go to your cPanel your node app
In the "Application startup file", replace your main file with loader.cjs
Save and restart your app.

Hope it will work with yours
